# How can I dynamically replace the contents of a module before bundle is created?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a case where I want to replace the contents of one file with the contents of another (JS) file.

Is there something similar to `string-replace-webpack-plugin` or a different way to do this?

I have a different case where I am replacing a match in the same file, but in another case I want to replace all of the contents.

Also, simply copying the file to the dest won't work, I need the contents to be in the bundle in place of the original content.

Being new to webpack, I am sure there is something super easy I am missing.

Thanks for any tips!